# Is variable allocated on stack if i return before its declaration?

Tags: c++

Assume i have a function whose rough structure looks like this:

```
int aRecursiveFunction(const SomeLargeStructure *a, int x) {
    if (end recursion)
        return 0;
    // ...
    if (something that is mostly true)
        return aRecursiveFunction(a, x+1)+1;
    // ...
    SomeLargeStructure copy = *a;
    alter(&copy);
    return aRecursiveFunction(&copy, x);
}
```

What i need to know is, for performance reasons, whether the space for `copy` (which is a large structure) will be created on the stack in the 90 % of cases where the function ends before this point. Or does it actually not even matter? Does it depend on the compiler? Is it better to separate this part as another function?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: To clarify, `sizeof(SomeLargeStructure)` is around 500, it only has basic types and arrays (no special constructors or assignment operators etc.).

**EDIT 2**: Alright, the conclusion seems to be that the stack space probably will be allocated every time but it doesn't impact performance. Stack overflow is not an issue here, so case closed.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing the compiler is free to do as it pleases. Even assuming that conditional stack allocation is possible,  allocating always is the likely choice if it optimizes for speed.

Comment: Do you think it takes longer to allocate 50,000 bytes of stack space than 48 bytes of stack space? On most platforms, allocating stack space is just addition.

Comment: I don't know, probably not, but that's why i'm asking.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It won't take any extra time, but it _might_ affect locality.  (In this case, I doubt it, but in general.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On most platforms, the maximum stack space that might be needed is allocated on function entry. But usually allocating stack space is just addition, so the amount of space allocated has no effect on performance.

Your question reads like premature optimization to me though. This isn't an algorithmic issue and you don't have a measured performance issue. So why are you even thinking about micro-optimizations?

Comment: That's true if we interpret "performance" as "speed". The actual stack size taken may still matter, e.g. for the question of how likely a stack overflow is.

Comment: @jogojapan I'm not sure how else "performance" could be meant here. I guess it's conceivable he might call a function that uses lots of stack space if and only if his large structure isn't allocated, but that seems incredibly improbable.

Comment: I don't see why it is premature. The actual function is much longer and more complicated, so i just posted its rough structure (as i said), to ask about this specific part. I've been actually trying to make it faster for some time.

Comment: @Detheroc the common procedure is to write your code and profile it afterwards to spot bottlenecks that need optimization. If that region proves to be the hotspot then you might consider taking a deeper look. Stack allocations aren't usually performance-intensive.

Comment: @Detheroc It's hard to imagine any sensible optimization strategy that lead you to stack allocation? You're almost certainly barking up a tree in the wrong forest.

Comment: It also influences performance: remember the cache, which is *very* important for the things on stack!

Comment: Well it just seemed logical to me that calling a function with a 1 kB stack frame a billion times might be slower than doing that with a smaller function.

Comment: @Detheroc Premature optimization will lead you down a lot of wrong paths. Don't do it. Algorithmic optimizations are fine, but micro-optimizations should be saved for demonstrated need.

Answer (score 4):

*Some* compilers *might* [optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) your [tail-recursive call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). When they do optimize, the call stack frame is reused so won't grow (so a tail-call is optimized as a "goto with arguments"). IIRC, for recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you are in the case where tail-call is not optimized (but I may be wrong, and GCC is progressing in that area).

You may want to compile to assembler code, e.g. with `g++ -fverbose-asm -S -Wall -O` and look into the generated assembler code to find out.

You certainly should not expect every C++ compiler to optimize tail calls like yours.

If it is so important for you, and if portability is less a concern, you might use [alloca(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) and then a placement new operator.

```
  SomeLargeStructure* copyptr = 
    new (alloca(sizeof(SomeLargeStructure))) SomeLargeStructure;
  *copyptr = *a;
  alter(copyptr);
  return aRecursiveFunction(copyptr, x);
```

<sup>If you have a copy constructor, use `new (alloca(sizeof(SomeLargeStructure))) SomeLargeStructure(*a);` instead.</sup>

BTW, I'm not sure it is worth the effort, for a call frame size of half a kilobyte, on modern desktops or servers (where stack space is often a bit more than a megabyte), unless you believe that your recursion is really deep (e.g. more than a thousand levels of recursion).

With recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you might be interested by compiler options like [-fstack-usage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) or [-Wstack-usage=](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Answer (score 3):

It really boils down to how much information the compiler can gain during its analysis on how your code will be executed at runtime. In the worst-case (i.e. a compiler can't infer if that data is ever going to be executed) the compiler necessarily **has** to allocate stack space for every function call:

```
struct SomeLargeStructure {
    double arr[20];
};

int aRecursiveFunction(const SomeLargeStructure *a, int x) {
    int val;
    cin >> val; // User input isn't foresee-able
    if (val == 29)
        return 0;
    // ...

    if (val)
        return aRecursiveFunction(a, x + 1) + 1;
    // ...
    SomeLargeStructure copy = *a;
    if (val == 22)
      copy.arr[0] = 2.0; // whatever
    return aRecursiveFunction(&copy, x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SomeLargeStructure obj;
    aRecursiveFunction(&obj, 2);
}
```

the above will require a full stack allocation at every call (`-O3`):

```
aRecursiveFunction(SomeLargeStructure const*, int):
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $176, %rsp // stack alloc
    movl    %esi, %ebx
    movq    %rdi, %r14
    leaq    172(%rsp), %rsi
```

Also in cases where human deduction might think "*this is definitely not needed*" a compiler might still choose to allocate stack space.

It is impossible to answer this question properly without seeing the full code and/or studying the compiler's behavior in that case. You should compile your code and look at the generated and optimized assembly yourself. Just allocating stack space isn't usually a performance concern (unless you have a stack overflow).

A word of advice though: this is usually a **premature optimization** as others have noted, you shouldn't worry for these low-level issue but rather concentrate on your algorithm and how your data is being used, especially because if your stack space consumption doesn't prove/seem to be a problem, it is the profiling phase that will hint you on the *red areas* where optimization is most needed.