# Maximum recursive function calls in C/C++ before stack is full and gives a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

I was doing a question where I used a recursive function to create a segment tree. For larger values it started giving segmentation fault. So I thought before it might be because of array index value out of bound but later I thought it might be because of program stack going too big.
I wrote this code to count what is the maximum number of recursive calls allowed before the system give seg-fault.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
void recur(long long int);
int main()
{
  recur(0);
  return 0;
}
void recur(long long int v)
{
  v++;
  cout<<v<<endl;
  recur(v);

}
```

After running the above code I got value of v to be 261926 and 261893 and 261816 before getting segmentation fault and all values were close to these.

Now I know that this would depend on machine to machine, and the size of the stack of the function being called but can someone explain the basics of how to keep safe from seg-faults and what is a soft limit that one can keep in mind.

Comment: to keep safe from seg faults don't use recursion.

Comment: While you're creating a tree the stack shouldn't grow any deeper than the tree, so there shouldn't be a problem unless your tree is huge and unbalanced (or your local variables and parameters are huge).

Comment: Recursion is just a "fancy" loop, most recursive functions can be replaced with loops. If you *must* use recursion, don't have large local arrays, and make sure the stopping condition works before you run out of stack, and only in the worst case scenario and as a last resort you increase the stack.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a recursion depth of O(log N) is no problem, but a recursion depth of O(N) is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The number of recursion levels you can do depends on the call-stack size combined with the size of local variables and arguments that are placed on such a stack. Aside from "how the code is written", just like many other memory related things, this is very much dependent on the system you're running on, what compiler you are using, optimisation level [1], and so on. Some embedded systems I've worked on, the stack would be a few hundred bytes, my first home computer had 256 bytes of stack, where modern desktops have megabytes of stack (and you can adjust it, but eventually you will run out)

Doing recursion at unlimited depth is not a good idea, and you should look at changing your code to so that "it doesn't do that". You need to understand the algorithm and understand to what depth it will recurse, and whether that is acceptable in your system. There is unfortunately nothing anyone can do at the time stack runs out (at best your program crashes, at worst it doesn't, but instead causes something ELSE to go wrong, such as the stack or heap of some other application gets messed up!)

On a desktop machine, I'd think it's acceptable to have a recursion depth of a hew hundred to some thousands, but not much more than this - and that is if you have small usage of stack in each call - if each call is using up kilobytes of stack, you should limit the call level even further, or reduce the need for stack-space.

If you need to have more recursion depth than that, you need to re-arrange the code - for example using a software stack to store the state, and a loop in the code itself.

[1] Using g++ -O2 on your posted code, I got to 50 million and counting, and I expect if I leave it long enough, it will restart at zero because it keeps going forever - this since g++ detects that this recursion can be converted into a loop, and does that. Same program compiled with -O0 or -O1 does indeed stop at a little over 200000. With clang++ -O1 it just keeps going. The clang-compiled code is still running as I finished writing the rest of the code, at 185 million "recursions".

Answer (score 7):

There is (AFAIK) no well established limit. (I am answering from a Linux desktop point of view).

On desktops, laptops the default stack size is a few megabytes in 2015. On Linux you could use [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) to change it (to a reasonable figure, don't expect to be able to set it to a gigabyte these days) - and you could use [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) or parse `/proc/self/limits` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) to query it . On embedded microcontrollers - or inside the Linux kernel- , the entire stack may be much more limited (to a few kilobytes in total).

When you create a thread using [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) you could use an explicit `pthread_attr_t` and use [pthread_attr_setstack(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstack.3.html) to set the stack space.

BTW, with recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you might compile all your software (*including* the standard C library) with [split stacks](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks) (so pass `-fsplit-stack` to `gcc` or `g++`)

At last your example is a [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), and GCC could optimize that (into a jump with arguments). I checked that if you compile with `g++ -O2` (using GCC 4.9.2 on Linux/x86-64/Debian) the recursion would be transformed into a genuine loop and no stack allocation would grow indefinitely (your program run for nearly 40 millions calls to `recur` in a minute, then I interrupted it) In better languages like Scheme or Ocaml there is a guarantee that tail calls are indeed compiled iteratively (then the tail recursive call becomes the usually -or even the only- looping construct).

[CyberSpok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45685/cyberspock) is excessive in his comment (hinting to avoid recursions). Recursions are very useful, but you should limit them to a reasonable depth (e.g. a few thousands), and you should take care that call frames on the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) are small (less than a kilobyte each), so practically allocate and deallocate most of the data in the [C heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). The GCC [-fstack-usage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) options is really useful for reporting stack usage of every compiled function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26463223/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30044429/841108) answers.

Notice that [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) is a canonical way to transform recursions into iterations (then you trade stack frames with dynamically allocated [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)).

Some clever algorithms replace a recursion with fancy modifying iterations, e.g. the [Deutche-Shorr-Waite graph marking algorithm](http://www.fastar.org/dads/HTML/SchorrWaiteGraphMarking.html).

Answer (score 1):

For Linux based applications, we can use getrlimit and setrlimit API's to know various kernel resource limits, like size of core file, cpu time, stack size, nice values, max. no. of processes etc. 'RLIMIT_STACK' is the resource name for stack defined in linux kernel. Below is simple program to retrieve stack size :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <errno.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   struct rlimit sl;
   int returnVal = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &sl);
   if (returnVal == -1)
   {
      cout << "Error. errno: " << errno << endl;
   }
   else if (returnVal == 0)
   {
      cout << "stackLimit soft - max : " << sl.rlim_cur << " - " << sl.rlim_max << endl;
   }
}
```