# How many number of times main function can be called recursively?

Tags: c

How many times the main function can be called recursively from the main function? Does the count depend on stack space?

Comment: @G.M. That is for C++, as far as I know no such rule exists for C.

Comment: @G.M. That is the wrong documentation main() can be called recursively in C (not in C++)

Comment: Check this similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208196/maximum-recursive-function-calls-in-c-c-before-stack-is-full-and-gives-a-segme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum recursive function calls in C/C++ before stack is full and gives a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208196/maximum-recursive-function-calls-in-c-c-before-stack-is-full-and-gives-a-segme)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it depends on stack space (except in cases where the compiler optimizes away the call, possibly in tail recursion). C implementations (and many programming languages and their implementations) are generally lax about documenting stack space use, so it is often difficult to calculate how many calls can be made, whether recursive or to various calls in a general call tree. If you are encountering problems due to limited stack space, you should probably try to design your code to use iterative solutions rather than recursive.

Answer (score 0):

523191 times

```
$ cat xx.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    puts("");
    main();
}
$ gcc xx.c && ./a.out |wc -l
523191
```

Comment: You're **wrong**!  Right program, wrong answer.  I ran the same program, and it gave me 196608, not 523191.  Not sure how you made such a severe typo. :-)  [P.S. I'm upvoting the answer anyway, because a meaninglessly precise answer is precisely what I was tempted to give.]